# Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA) always denied in standalone apk in Android EXPO SDK 37

Tags: react-native

I am using Expo sdk 37.0.1 & asking for camera and gallery permission. It's working in local expo device & emulator but when I build APK installed in real device it's always denied. Below is the code to get/set permission.

```
const resultCamera = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
```

I also added permission in app.json file which seems to be correct as per documentation of expo itself which is needed for standalone app.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#android-permissions-equivalents-inside-appjson
App.json code as below

```
"android": {
  "versionCode": 9,
  "permissions": [
    "CAMERA",
    "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  ]
},
```

I also log the output of standalone app of  `const resultCamera = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA)`

```
"resultCamera": {
"status": "denied",
"expires": "never",
"canAskAgain": false,
"granted": false,
"permissions": {
  "camera": {
    "granted": false,
    "status": "denied",
    "canAskAgain": false,
    "expires": "never"
  }
}
}
```

My sdk package of react native is as below

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem with the expo-av microphone permissions. In the expo client the permissions work flawlessly but when I had to eject to use some native modules the permissions got wacky. On Android, the `canAskAgain` permission always returned false (I haven't got around to ios).I found a workaround for my issue that may be useful for you.

Triggering a permission request hinged on the permission not being granted and the ability to ask again. But expo-av defaults permissions.canAskAgain to false so I did this:

```js
 async function getPermissions(){
    let permissions = await Audio.getPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(permissions)
    setCanUseMic(permissions.granted);
    if(!permissions.granted){
      console.log('Requesting mic permissions')
      try{
        await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
        // update permissions
        permissions = await Audio.getPermissionsAsync();
        setCanUseMic(permissions.granted);
      }catch(err){
        if(!permission.canAskAgain){
          console.log('Unable to ask again for mic permissions')
          // use an alert to tell user to go to settings to enable mic permissions
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Instead of checking permissions.canAskAgain, I simply request the permission. So far, it works out fine